# DocuSign Connect response is null everytime

Tags: c#, wcf, docusignapi

Im trying to setup a connect listener. I am currently using a C# WCF Service that Im hosting on Azure. Im able to hit my service method but the response from docusign is null every time. In the logs, the envelope status xml has values but it is just not sent or not deserialized correctly. Im not sure what I am doing wrong and there doesnt seem to be any solid examples of a SOAP implementation anywhere. Can anyone help? The WSDL can be viewed here http://docusignconnectservice.azurewebsites.net/Service.svc?wsdl

Service Implentation

```
public string DocuSignConnectUpdate(DocuSignAPI.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation     envelopeInformation)
    {

        string envelopeId = "";

            if (envelopeInformation == null) return "Envelope is null";
            else return envelopeInformation.EnvelopeStatus.EnvelopeID;
    }
```

Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0")]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute]
    string DocuSignConnectUpdate(DocuSignAPI.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation envelopeInformation);

    [OperationContract]
    string HelloWorld(string inputString);
```

DocuSign log entry

`10/6/2014 1:30:12 AM  Envelope Data:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>email</Email><UserName>Username</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2014-10-05T17:49:36.58</Sent><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Sent</Status><RecipientIPAddress /><CustomFields /><AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus><RecipientId>2a10b0ab-63f1-4df9-9258-36b97b5db120</RecipientId></RecipientStatus></RecipientStatuses><TimeGenerated>2014-10-05T18:30:09.644588</TimeGenerated><EnvelopeID>6d7692e6-3f5c-4889-914f-942b2bd83447</EnvelopeID><Subject> Signature Request on Document</Subject><UserName>Username</UserName><Email>email</Email><Status>Sent</Status><Created>2014-10-05T17:49:35.503</Created> <Sent>2014-10-05T17:49:36.613</Sent><ACStatus>Original</ACStatus><ACStatusDate>2014-10-05T17:49:35.503</ACStatusDate><ACHolder></ACHolder><ACHolderEmail></ACHolderEmail><ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation><SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation><SenderIPAddress>ip </SenderIPAddress><EnvelopePDFHash /><CustomFields /><AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation><EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping><AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy><DocumentStatuses><DocumentStatus><ID>1</ID><Name>F_1040.pdf</Name><TemplateName /><Sequence>1</Sequence></DocumentStatus></DocumentStatuses></EnvelopeStatus></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
10/6/2014 1:30:12 AM  Response: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><DocuSignConnectUpdateResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><DocuSignConnectUpdateResult>Envelope is  null</DocuSignConnectUpdateResult></DocuSignConnectUpdateResponse></s:Body>    </s:Envelope>`

Comment: What does the raw POST body that your http listener is receiving from DocuSign look like?  You should be able to capture through a tool like Fiddler and examine its contents, that should help figure out why not deserializing correctly...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? We are experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with your classes for mapping of XML.
You can configure your classes with XML response you have  with online tools like http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and use XMLSerializer to parse that XML into object .